# Unable to install OrionJS for Meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-orion

I've been trying to get this to work, to no avail. I created a completely fresh app and added ONLY orionjs:core just to test it out, but received this error message. What can I do?

My steps:
1. `meteor create BWW`

2. `meteor npm install`
3. `meteor add orionjs:core` => This failed and the error message is below

   => Errors while adding packages:

   ```
   While loading npm-bcrypt@0.7.7...:
   error: Command failed:
   /Users/Gaurav/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2_3.1rd9djy++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/npm
   rebuild --update-binary
   ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:118:18: error: no member named 'Dispose' in 'v8::Persistent<v8::Function,
   v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Function> >'
   callback.Dispose();
   ~~~~~~~~ ^
   ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:202:19: error: unknown type name 'uv_work_t'
   void GenSaltAsync(uv_work_t* req) {
   ^
   ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:219:24: error: unknown type name 'uv_work_t'
   void GenSaltAsyncAfter(uv_work_t* req) {
   ^
   ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:220:17: error: calling a protected constructor of class 'v8::HandleScope'
   HandleScope scope;
   ^
   /Users/Gaurav/.node-gyp/4.6.2/include/node/v8.h:885:13: note: declared protected here
   V8_INLINE HandleScope() {}
   ^
   ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:228:44: error: no member named 'New' in 'v8::String'
   argv[0] = Exception::Error(String::New(baton->error.c_str()));
   ~~~~~~~~^
   ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:229:19: error: no matching function for call to 'Undefined'
   argv[1] = Undefined();
   ^~~~~~~~~
   /Users/Gaurav/.node-gyp/4.6.2/include/node/v8.h:315:27: note: candidate function not viable: requires single argument 'isolate', but
   no arguments were provided
   friend Local<Primitive> Undefined(Isolate* isolate);
   ^
   ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:232:19: error: no matching function for call to 'Undefined'
   argv[0] = Undefined();
   ^~~~~~~~~
   /Users/Gaurav/.node-gyp/4.6.2/include/node/v8.h:315:27: note: candidate function not viable: requires single argument 'isolate', but
   no arguments were provided
   friend Local<Primitive> Undefined(Isolate* isolate);
   ^
   ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:233:19: warning: 'Encode' is deprecated: Use Encode(isolate, ...) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   argv[1] = Encode(baton->salt.c_str(), baton->salt.size(), BINARY);
   ^
   /Users/Gaurav/.node-gyp/4.6.2/include/node/node.h:300:45: note: 'Encode' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
   inline v8::Local<v8::Value> Encode(
   ^
   /Users/Gaurav/.node-gyp/4.6.2/include/node/node.h:66:42: note: expanded from macro 'NODE_DEPRECATED'
   __attribute__((deprecated(message))) declarator
   ^
   ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:238:20: error: member reference type 'v8::Persistent<v8::Function>' is not a pointer; maybe you meant to use
   '.'?
   baton->callback->Call(Context::GetCurrent()->Global(), 2, argv);
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
   .
   ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:238:22: error: no member named 'Call' in 'v8::Persistent<v8::Function,
   v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Function> >'
   baton->callback->Call(Context::GetCurrent()->Global(), 2, argv);
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
   ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:238:36: error: no member named 'GetCurrent' in 'v8::Context'
   baton->callback->Call(Context::GetCurrent()->Global(), 2, argv);
   ~~~~~~~~~^
   ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:241:9: warning: 'FatalException' is deprecated: Use FatalException(isolate, ...)
   [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   FatalException(try_catch);
   ^
   /Users/Gaurav/.node-gyp/4.6.2/include/node/node.h:284:29: note: 'FatalException' has been explicitly marked deprecated
   here
   inline void FatalException(const v8::TryCatch& try_catch) {
   ^
   /Users/Gaurav/.node-gyp/4.6.2/include/node/node.h:66:42: note: expanded from macro 'NODE_DEPRECATED'
   __attribute__((deprecated(message))) declarator
   ^
   ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:246:34: error: unknown type name 'Arguments'; did you mean 'v8::internal::Arguments'?
   Handle<Value> GenerateSalt(const Arguments &args) {
   ^~~~~~~~~
   v8::internal::Arguments
   /Users/Gaurav/.node-gyp/4.6.2/include/node/v8.h:139:7: note: 'v8::internal::Arguments' declared here
   class Arguments;
   ^
   ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:247:17: error: calling a protected constructor of class 'v8::HandleScope'
   HandleScope scope;
   ^
   /Users/Gaurav/.node-gyp/4.6.2/include/node/v8.h:885:13: note: declared protected here
   V8_INLINE HandleScope() {}
   ^
   ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:249:32: error: type 'const v8::internal::Arguments' does not provide a subscript operator
   const ssize_t rounds = args[0]->Int32Value();
   ~~~~^~
   ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:250:30: error: type 'const v8::internal::Arguments' does not provide a subscript operator
   const int rand_len = args[1]->Int32Value();
   ~~~~^~
   ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:251:58: error: type 'const v8::internal::Arguments' does not provide a subscript operator
   Local<Function> callback = Local<Function>::Cast(args[2]);
   ~~~~^~
   ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:255:45: error: 'New' is a private member of 'v8::PersistentBase<v8::Function>'
   baton->callback = Persistent<Function>::New(callback);
   ^
   /Users/Gaurav/.node-gyp/4.6.2/include/node/v8.h:639:23: note: declared private here
   V8_INLINE static T* New(Isolate* isolate, T* that);
   ^
   ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:255:57: error: too few arguments to function call, expected 2, have 1
   baton->callback = Persistent<Function>::New(callback);
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~         ^
   /Users/Gaurav/.node-gyp/4.6.2/include/node/v8.h:639:3: note: 'New' declared here
   V8_INLINE static T* New(Isolate* isolate, T* that);
   ^
   /Users/Gaurav/.node-gyp/4.6.2/include/node/v8config.h:301:20: note: expanded from macro 'V8_INLINE'
   # define V8_INLINE inline __attribute__((always_inline))
   ^
   ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:259:5: error: unknown type name 'uv_work_t'
   uv_work_t* req = new uv_work_t;
   ^
   ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:259:26: error: unknown type name 'uv_work_t'
   uv_work_t* req = new uv_work_t;
   ^
   fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
   2 warnings and 20 errors generated.
   make: *** [Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt_node.o] Error 1
   gyp ERR! build error 
   gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
   gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit
   (/Users/Gaurav/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2_3.1rd9djy++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:276:23)
   gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
   gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
   gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:12)
   gyp ERR! System Darwin 14.5.0
   gyp ERR! command
   "/Users/Gaurav/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2_3.1rd9djy++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node"
   "/Users/Gaurav/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2_3.1rd9djy++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js"
   "rebuild"
   gyp ERR! cwd /private/var/folders/rt/mkj18hjd42j0prvy63hlj0fw0000gq/T/mt-9hsn4u/npm/node_modules/.temp-849lte/node_modules/bcrypt
   gyp ERR! node -v v4.6.2
   gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
   gyp ERR! not ok 

   npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0
   npm ERR! argv
   "/Users/Gaurav/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2_3.1rd9djy++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node"
   "/Users/Gaurav/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2_3.1rd9djy++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/npm"
   "rebuild" "--update-binary"
   npm ERR! node v4.6.2
   npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
   npm ERR! bcrypt@0.7.7 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
   npm ERR! Exit status 1
   npm ERR! 
   npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@0.7.7 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
   npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
   npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the bcrypt package,
   npm ERR! not with npm itself.
   npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
   npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
   npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
   npm ERR!     npm bugs bcrypt
   npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
   npm ERR!     npm owner ls bcrypt
   npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

   npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
   npm ERR!     /private/var/folders/rt/mkj18hjd42j0prvy63hlj0fw0000gq/T/mt-9hsn4u/npm/node_modules/.temp-849lte/npm-debug.log
   ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:118:18: error: no member named 'Dispose' in 'v8::Persistent<v8::Function,
   v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Function> >'
   callback.Dispose();
   ~~~~~~~~ ^
   ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:202:19: error: unknown type name 'uv_work_t'
   void GenSaltAsync(uv_work_t* req) {
   ^
   ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:219:24: error: unknown type name 'uv_work_t'
   void GenSaltAsyncAfter(uv_work_t* req) {
   ^
   ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:220:17: error: calling a protected constructor of class 'v8::HandleScope'
   HandleScope scope;
   ^
   /Users/Gaurav/.node-gyp/4.6.2/include/node/v8.h:885:13: note: declared protected here
   V8_INLINE HandleScope() {}
   ^
   ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:228:44: error: no member named 'New' in 'v8::String'
   argv[0] = Exception::Error(String::New(baton->error.c_str()));
   ~~~~~~~~^
   ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:229:19: error: no matching function for call to 'Undefined'
   argv[1] = Undefined();
   ^~~~~~~~~
   /Users/Gaurav/.node-gyp/4.6.2/include/node/v8.h:315:27: note: candidate function not viable: requires single argument 'isolate', but
   no arguments were provided
   friend Local<Primitive> Undefined(Isolate* isolate);
   ^
   ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:232:19: error: no matching function for call to 'Undefined'
   argv[0] = Undefined();
   ^~~~~~~~~
   /Users/Gaurav/.node-gyp/4.6.2/include/node/v8.h:315:27: note: candidate function not viable: requires single argument 'isolate', but
   no arguments were provided
   friend Local<Primitive> Undefined(Isolate* isolate);
   ^
   ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:233:19: warning: 'Encode' is deprecated: Use Encode(isolate, ...) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   argv[1] = Encode(baton->salt.c_str(), baton->salt.size(), BINARY);
   ^
   /Users/Gaurav/.node-gyp/4.6.2/include/node/node.h:300:45: note: 'Encode' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
   inline v8::Local<v8::Value> Encode(
   ^
   /Users/Gaurav/.node-gyp/4.6.2/include/node/node.h:66:42: note: expanded from macro 'NODE_DEPRECATED'
   __attribute__((deprecated(message))) declarator
   ^
   ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:238:20: error: member reference type 'v8::Persistent<v8::Function>' is not a pointer; maybe you meant to use
   '.'?
   baton->callback->Call(Context::GetCurrent()->Global(), 2, argv);
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
   .
   ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:238:22: error: no member named 'Call' in 'v8::Persistent<v8::Function,
   v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Function> >'
   baton->callback->Call(Context::GetCurrent()->Global(), 2, argv);
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
   ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:238:36: error: no member named 'GetCurrent' in 'v8::Context'
   baton->callback->Call(Context::GetCurrent()->Global(), 2, argv);
   ~~~~~~~~~^
   ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:241:9: warning: 'FatalException' is deprecated: Use FatalException(isolate, ...)
   [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   FatalException(try_catch);
   ^
   /Users/Gaurav/.node-gyp/4.6.2/include/node/node.h:284:29: note: 'FatalException' has been explicitly marked deprecated
   here
   inline void FatalException(const v8::TryCatch& try_catch) {
   ^
   /Users/Gaurav/.node-gyp/4.6.2/include/node/node.h:66:42: note: expanded from macro 'NODE_DEPRECATED'
   __attribute__((deprecated(message))) declarator
   ^
   ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:246:34: error: unknown type name 'Arguments'; did you mean 'v8::internal::Arguments'?
   Handle<Value> GenerateSalt(const Arguments &args) {
   ^~~~~~~~~
   v8::internal::Arguments
   /Users/Gaurav/.node-gyp/4.6.2/include/node/v8.h:139:7: note: 'v8::internal::Arguments' declared here
   class Arguments;
   ^
   ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:247:17: error: calling a protected constructor of class 'v8::HandleScope'
   HandleScope scope;
   ^
   /Users/Gaurav/.node-gyp/4.6.2/include/node/v8.h:885:13: note: declared protected here
   V8_INLINE HandleScope() {}
   ^
   ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:249:32: error: type 'const v8::internal::Arguments' does not provide a subscript operator
   const ssize_t rounds = args[0]->Int32Value();
   ~~~~^~
   ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:250:30: error: type 'const v8::internal::Arguments' does not provide a subscript operator
   const int rand_len = args[1]->Int32Value();
   ~~~~^~
   ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:251:58: error: type 'const v8::internal::Arguments' does not provide a subscript operator
   Local<Function> callback = Local<Function>::Cast(args[2]);
   ~~~~^~
   ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:255:45: error: 'New' is a private member of 'v8::PersistentBase<v8::Function>'
   baton->callback = Persistent<Function>::New(callback);
   ^
   /Users/Gaurav/.node-gyp/4.6.2/include/node/v8.h:639:23: note: declared private here
   V8_INLINE static T* New(Isolate* isolate, T* that);
   ^
   ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:255:57: error: too few arguments to function call, expected 2, have 1
   baton->callback = Persistent<Function>::New(callback);
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~         ^
   /Users/Gaurav/.node-gyp/4.6.2/include/node/v8.h:639:3: note: 'New' declared here
   V8_INLINE static T* New(Isolate* isolate, T* that);
   ^
   /Users/Gaurav/.node-gyp/4.6.2/include/node/v8config.h:301:20: note: expanded from macro 'V8_INLINE'
   # define V8_INLINE inline __attribute__((always_inline))
   ^
   ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:259:5: error: unknown type name 'uv_work_t'
   uv_work_t* req = new uv_work_t;
   ^
   ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:259:26: error: unknown type name 'uv_work_t'
   uv_work_t* req = new uv_work_t;
   ^
   fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
   2 warnings and 20 errors generated.
   make: *** [Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt_node.o] Error 1
   gyp ERR! build error 
   gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
   gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit
   (/Users/Gaurav/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2_3.1rd9djy++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:276:23)
   gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
   gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
   gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:12)
   gyp ERR! System Darwin 14.5.0
   gyp ERR! command
   "/Users/Gaurav/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2_3.1rd9djy++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node"
   "/Users/Gaurav/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2_3.1rd9djy++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js"
   "rebuild"
   gyp ERR! cwd /private/var/folders/rt/mkj18hjd42j0prvy63hlj0fw0000gq/T/mt-9hsn4u/npm/node_modules/.temp-849lte/node_modules/bcrypt
   gyp ERR! node -v v4.6.2
   gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
   gyp ERR! not ok 

   npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0
   npm ERR! argv
   "/Users/Gaurav/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2_3.1rd9djy++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node"
   "/Users/Gaurav/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2_3.1rd9djy++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/npm"
   "rebuild" "--update-binary"
   npm ERR! node v4.6.2
   npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
   npm ERR! bcrypt@0.7.7 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
   npm ERR! Exit status 1
   npm ERR! 
   npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@0.7.7 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
   npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
   npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the bcrypt package,
   npm ERR! not with npm itself.
   npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
   npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
   npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
   npm ERR!     npm bugs bcrypt
   npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
   npm ERR!     npm owner ls bcrypt
   npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

   npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
   npm ERR!     /private/var/folders/rt/mkj18hjd42j0prvy63hlj0fw0000gq/T/mt-9hsn4u/npm/node_modules/.temp-849lte/npm-debug.log
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem on OSX with Meteor 1.4.2.3, I solved it with:

```
meteor npm install
meteor npm install --save bcrypt
meteor add npm-bcrypt@0.8.7
meteor add orionjs:core
meteor add iron:router
```